# Subjekt in Satz mit „gefallen“

Tags: grammatical-case

Ich mache eine Übung und ich muss das Subjekt in Sätzen finden.  Was wäre das Subjekt in diesem Satz: „Den Beamten dort gefällt sein(**em**) Aussehen nicht“?  Ist es „Aussehen“?  danke.

Comment: There seems to be an error in your original sentence, which I have highlighted. Feel free to correct.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the sentence is correct in the first place. I'd expect something like "Sein Aussehen gefällt den Beamten dort nicht", not "Seinem Aussehen ...". It is not his look that doesn't like something, it is the look that isn't liked. And yes, Aussehen is the Subject then.

Comment: Thank you for a feedback.

Answer (score 1):

(Das wahrscheinlich falsch geschriebene und vom Editor @Ingmar korrigierte "seinem" [statt "sein"] habe ich in der Antwort stillschweigend als korrigiert vorausgesetzt.)

Das Subjekt in einem Satz ist ein Nomen (Substantiv) und steht immer im Nominativ. Der Fall läßt sich im Deutschen durch Fragestellung feststellen:

> Den Beamten dort gefällt sein Aussehen nicht.

Es gibt hier nur zwei Nomen, nämlich "Beamter" und "Aussehen". Bleiben also nur diese beiden Möglichkeiten.

> *Wem oder was* gefällt das Aussehen nicht?

Den Beamten. Das ist also Dativ und deshalb ein *Objekt*.

> *Wer oder was* gefällt nicht? Das (sein) Aussehen. Aha!

Deine Vermutung, es sei das "Aussehen" war also richtig.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Erklärung!

Comment: Und eine Frage: in Imperative - ob ich richtig bin, dann es kein Subjekt gibt? Zum Beispiel: „Machen Sie sich eine normale Frisur!“.

Comment: @Sergey: auch in Imperativsätzen gibt es ein Subjekt - es ist derjenige, an den der Imperativ gerichtet ist. In deinem Beispiel wäre das also "Sie".

Comment: Wieder einmal: Das "Frage stellen" nach Subjekt oder Objekt zur Feststellung des Kasus ist für einen Fremdsprachler, dem das Sprachgefühl (noch) fehlt, wesentlich nutzloser (nämlich praktisch vollkommen), als der Muttersprachler denkt.

Comment: Erstens: Die Begriffe [Substantiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantiv) und [Nomen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomen) sind nicht zwangsweise Synonyme. Wenn man keine Adjektive, Pronomen usw., sondern ausdrücklich nur Substantive meint, sollte man der Klarheit wegen auch genau diesen Begriff verwenden. Zweitens: Die beiden Substantive in diesem Satz sind weder Subjekte noch Objekte. Sie sind die Kerne zweier [Nominalphrasen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalphrase). Die Nominalphrase *»sein Aussehen«* ist das Subjekt und die Nominalphrase *»den Beamten dort«* ist das Dativobjekt.

Comment: Erstens habe ich "Substantiv" und "Nomen" weder synonym verwendet noch unterstellt, daß es Synonyme, welcher Art auch immer, wären - schon gar keine "zwangsweisen". Darüber hinaus habe ich nicht "Substantive" gemeint (sonst hätte ich das nämlich geschrieben). Daß nicht nur Substantive Subjekte sein können, geht etwa aus dem Satz "Du bist kleinlich" hervor, in dem das Subjekt ein Personalpronomen ist. Den Hinweis auf Nominalphrasen habe ich mir angesichts des (vermuteten) Lernniveaus des Fragestellers geschenkt. Auf die Frage nach "1+1=?" antworte ich auch nicht mit dem Hauptsatz der Algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Weitere Möglichkeit:

Das **Subjekt** ist immer **der Satzteil, mit dem das** (konjugierte / definite) **Verb *in Person und Zahl* zusammenpasst**:

> *Den Beamten* = **Plural** (Dativ), *sein Aussehen* = **Singular** (Nominativ oder Akkusativ) - *gefällt* = **Singular**, also ist *sein Aussehen* das Subjekt.

Da jedoch das Subjekt, wie bakunin schrieb, immer im Nominativ steht, ist die Sache schon durch den Kasus Nominativ klar.

Das Problem, hier das Subjekt zu erkennen, ergibt sich einerseits aus dem Fehler "sein(**em**)", andererseits aus der Verschiebung des Dativobjekts an den Satzanfang (statt: *Sein Aussehen gefiel den Beamten dort nicht*) und aus der gegenüber *nicht mögen / missbilligen* anderen Zuordnung der beiden syntaktischen Rollen Subjekt und Objekt:

> *Die Beamten* (Subjekt Nom. Plural) *mochten* (3. Person Plural) *sein Aussehen* (Akk.-Objekt Singular) *nicht = sie* (Subj. Nom. Plur.) *missbilligten sein Aussehen* (Akk.-Obj. Sing.).

Man könnte weitere Möglichkeiten finden, z.B. umgangssprachlich:

> *Die Beamten* (Subj. Nom. Plur.) *hatten etwas* (Akk. Sing.) *gegen sein Aussehen* (präpositionales Objekt mit 'gegen + Akk. Sing.').

Das indefinite *etwas* ist in diesem Satz kein vollwertiges Objekt und vergleichbar einem semantisch leeren Subjekt *es*. Der Satz beruht auf der recht stabilen idiomatischen Struktur *etwas gegen jemanden / gegen etwas haben*.

Manchmal lassen sich Subjekt und Objekt nicht unterscheiden, z.B. bei Namen:

> Anna gefällt Peter.

Das sollte (kontextfrei) eigentlich nach der englischen S-V-O-Regel interpretiert werden: *Die Anna gefällt dem Peter*, obwohl die umgekehrte Interpretation *ihr gefällt der Peter* ebenfalls möglich wäre.